# How to add a profile-plugin field to the users list in an override layout of com_users?

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla, how do you add a profile-plugin field to the user's list in an override layout of `com_users`? I created an override for the users list of the `com_users` component (in the html folder of my template). I would like to add a field of a custom profile plugin I made to the list (I want to see it on the list, for every row, without having to click on the user).

How do I go about doing this? A plugin? Maybe I can override just a function of a controller? Or maybe there is a means to override the `view.html.php` file and directly call a new model?

Comment: some minor cosmetical changes, "please" removal

Comment: Just to clarify: are you talking about an administrator-template or a site template? I cannot see there is a users - view in the frontend, so I'm guessing you are in the backend, or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi! Not sure if you know, but there is a dedicated Joomla! community at Stackexchange. You will have a better change to get an answer if you ask your question there. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/